# Linux: Finer-grain control of INET listen socket binding?

Tags: linux, sockets, interface, bind, listen

I have interfaces `lo`, `eth0`, and `eth0:1`.

`progA` creates a listen socket, and binds it to port `p` on `INADDR_ANY`.

Simultaneously, I would like to use `ncat` to port forward, listening on the same port `p`, but only on the IP address associated with `eth0:1`.   As expected, `ncat` is failing with "address already in use".

What I would like to be able to do is: have `progA` bind its listen socket to the addresses associated with interfaces `lo` and `eth0`, but not to the address associated with `eth0:1`, leaving that address open for `ncat` to bind to.

Is there an alternative to `INADDR_ANY` that allows binding to multiple interfaces and/or multiple IP addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separately bind to each of the individual interfaces using different sockets. Alternatively, you could write a program using [libpcap](http://www.google.com/search?q=libpcap) to capture packets on eth0:1 and forward them. Packet capturing lets you observe an interface without actually binding to it.